# Remove sections from OLE compound stream implementation

Tags: python, ole

I have tried implementing with python a deletion of size x starting at offset y from a certain stream.
I have used olefile parser for that, but they don't provide such operation, so I decided implementing it myself using olefile parser.

I considered a few cases as following:

1. The size plus the offset still inside one sector. In this case, I have just reset the bytes to be removed with '\x00'.
2. The size plus the offset crosses one sector, but in total it reaches only two sectors.
   In this case, I did exactly as (1), but for both sectors.
3. The size plus the offset is spread on multiple sectors. In this case, there are complete sectors to remove, so I though of mark them in FAT as unused and also reset the data inside each, also reset the data in the edge sectors. In addition, the size of the stream needs to be updated as well, but I can't think about more pointers that need to be changed.

Now, I don't know if I am doing well because it's complex, so I will be glad to see if I am on the right way.

Thanks!